# Does moving a partition change its UUID?

Tags: fedora, boot, move-partition

I'm running Fedora 36 with a BTFS root partition, a Swap partition and an ext4 Boot partition.

I ended up needing more space on my root partition for a couple of reasons and so I wish to delete my swap partition, move my boot partition to the end of the free space created by the deletion, and add the free space to my root partition.

What I don't want is that I render my system unbootable by the changes. The first question is thus would moving the boot partition without changing its size change its UUID? I'm asking this because, if I remember well, the boot process refers to the boot partition with its UUID.

Comment: Why not just add a second HDD or NAS? Much less hassle, much more reliable.

Answer (score 0):

The UUID is generated at the time the partition is created. If you are indeed only moving the partition, it should keep the same UUID. If the move is accomplished by creating a new partition and copying the data, then it would get a new UUID.

You are correct, newer grub bootloader configurations use the UUID to find your boot partition, so if the UUID remains the same then it should be able to find the right partition in its new location and boot from it.

Of course, messing with partitions always carries some risk so all important data should be backed up. You should also be prepared to reinstall grub in case you do have issues booting, either [manually](https://askubuntu.com/q/145241/15341) or with something like [Boot Repair.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)